# Select tag HTML not showing up in the DOM ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms

I'm currently rendering a react component that should have a select option form, but the select is not rendering. Not just in this component, but throughout the entire app. Not sure exactly what's going on, but feels like a really obvious answer that I am simply not getting. I'm currently using the MERN stack, with react-redux. The following is the code:

```
render () {
    const { book } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="book">
        <div className="book-cover" style={{ width: 128, height: 193, backgroundImage: `url(${book["imageLinks"]["thumbnail"]}`}}></div>
        <div className="book-title">{book["title"]}</div>
        <p>{book["authors"]}</p>
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <select id="status" name="status" onChange={this.setStatus}>
            <option value="" >Add to...</option>
            <option value="currentlyReading">Currently Reading</option>
            <option value="wantToRead">Want to Read</option>
            <option value="read">Read</option>
          </select>
          <Button color="dark" block> Add Book </Button>
        </form>
        </div>
```

The select form just doesn't show up anywhere on the screen. Not sure what to make of this issue, any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If the form doesn't show up anywhere then your component is not rendering at all. The issue is somewhere else and not related to the code you posted. Do you have see an error in your the console?

Comment: Are you saying that everything else is showing up, such as the book title and so on, but not the select?

Comment: @chris everything renders, book titles, authors, image, button, but not the select.

Comment: @goto1 the rest of the form renders — everything but the select portion....

Comment: If you "View Page Source", do you see the code for the `select` input? It doesn't make sense why it's not being rendered unless some `CSS` code is hiding it.

Comment: @goto1 you were indeed right that it was a CSS error -- it turns out the materialize stylesheet i was using has a unique way of using select forms...